# Swift 4 hex string to binary string

Tags: swift, binary, hex

Noted that the old method to convert a hex string to a binary string has been removed from swift i.e. : String(hex, radix: 2) -> binary string

What is an alternative in swift 4?

Comment: Update your question with an example of how you used the removed function.

Answer (score 5):

You need first to convert your hexaString to an Array of Bytes `[UInt8]`. Then you can use `String(_, radix:)` to convert the bytes to binary. Note that if you would like to return a `String` instead of an array of strings `[String]` you would need to add leading zeros to make your binary strings length consistent (8 characters):

```
extension String {
    typealias Byte = UInt8
    var hexaToBytes: [Byte] {
        var start = startIndex
        return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: 2).compactMap { _ in   // use flatMap for older Swift versions
            let end = index(after: start)
            defer { start = index(after: end) }
            return Byte(self[start...end], radix: 16)
        }
    }
    var hexaToBinary: String {
        return hexaToBytes.map {
            let binary = String($0, radix: 2)
            return repeatElement("0", count: 8-binary.count) + binary
        }.joined()
    }
}
```

---

```
let hexString = "00ff01fe"

hexString.hexaToBinary   // "00000000111111110000000111111110"
```

Comment: When I am using this , i am getting this error:- Fatal error: Can't advance past endIndex...     Please help me to solve this.

Comment: this probably means you are getting an extra byte. You should receive an even amount of bytes. You can check the bytes count. Can you post a link to the file with the data thats failing?

Comment: You need to drop the 0x prefixes

Answer (score 4):

I don't recall any function that would convert a hex string to another string of arbitrary radix. Perhaps you are thinking about the initializer functions that convert between strings and integer values (and vice versa) using an arbitrary radix:

```
let hex = "00ff01fe"
let value = UInt64(hex, radix: 16)!
let binary = String(value, radix: 2)
let paddedBinary = repeatElement("0", count: 64 - binary.count) + binary
```

But that only applies when the hex string represents a 64 bit value, but it illustrates the basic idea. Convert to some integer type, and then convert back to binary, padding it out with zeros.

If you have a hex string that is longer than that, you cannot use the above. But you can map the individual characters of your hex string to numeric values, build binary representation of each, zero pad them, and use `joined` to concatenate them together:

```
let hex = "ffeeddccbbaa99887766554433221100"

let result = hex.compactMap { c -> String? in
    guard let value = Int(String(c), radix: 16) else { return nil }
    let string = String(value, radix: 2)
    return repeatElement("0", count: 4 - string.count) + string
}.joined()
```

Comment: Please note that with this answer, "hex" max length is 16 chars (otherwise "value" will be nil)
With more wide hex string, use Leo Dabus answer.

Comment: @pw2 - Not true. Sure, the first snippet only works for 64 bit values, but the point of that was just to walk the reader through the pattern of converting hex string to integer and then convert that integer to binary string. But the second code snippet handles hex strings of arbitrary length (and gracefully handles white space or the like in the hex string, which Leo’s answer doesn’t).

Comment: @rob I agree with you.